# Problems animating bones

Tags: keyframes

I'm trying to do some animation but, for some reason, when I try to move the arms and make new keyframes, they keep connecting to the old ones. Even after I try to alter them separately, they keep ending up with the exact same pose! Is there something here I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: you cannot change that manually. Blender just shows by that connections that your values on both ends are equal. If you change the value on one side, the connection  will disappear.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You are setting the pose values and then adding the keyframes, right?